# Stop animation after time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

My application's main screen contains a SliverAppBar with three TabBarViews.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _loaded
        ? Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: mainBgColor,
            body: MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData(
                iconTheme: iconsStyle,
              ),
              home: NestedScrollView(
                controller: _scrollViewController,
                headerSliverBuilder:
                    (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
                  return <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
                      collapsedHeight: 80,
                      title: Text(
                        actor.name,
                        style: kNavTextStyle,
                      ),
                      leading: IconButtonWidget(false),
                                          iconTheme: kBackButtonStyle,
                      centerTitle: true,
                      backgroundColor: thirdColor,
                      pinned: true,
                      floating: true,
                      forceElevated: boxIsScrolled,
                      bottom: TabBar(
                        labelColor: secondaryColor,
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'DynaPuff',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                            fontSize: 17),
                        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                        indicator: const BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                          color: mainBgColor,
                        ),
                        tabs: _tabs,
                        controller: _tabController,
                      ),
                    )
                  ];
                },
                body: TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: _tabBars,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : const LoadingWidget();
  }
```

The first of the _tabBars contains an image that has an animation. The first time (when the app is loaded) I want to show this animation and then stop it. The problem is if I change the tab and step back to the first tab, the animation is shown again.

Is there any way to take care of it?

This is  the code of the widget with the animation:

```
 AnimationController _animController;

  Animation<Offset> _animation;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _animController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      vsync: this,
    )..forward();
    _animation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
      end: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animController,
      curve: Curves.decelerate,
    ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: _animation,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 250,
              child: Image.asset('images/hurray.png'),
            ),
            Text(
              cardText,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a bool somewhere in your state :

```
bool _firstTime = true;
```

then listen your animController

```
animController = AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  vsync: this,
)..addStatusListener((status) { 
  if(status == AnimationStatus.completed){
    setState(() {
      //set _firstTime to false;
       _firstTime = false;
    });
  }
});
if(_firstTime){
  _animController.forward();
}
```

Comment: Somehow when I change the tab the widget gets loaded again, so the _firstTime will be true again.

Comment: well you got a lot of options, give a key to each `_tabBars` childreen to preserve its state, || or warp each `_tabBars` view with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin,|| or put _firstTime somewhere safe not affected by tab bar view rebuild (when switch between view) maybe use a state management package

Comment: i prefer to warp your childreen with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin : MainWidget(where the _tabController located) -> tab bar view (give mixin here) -> then animation widget(Warp your animation widget into stateful widget, you need a another mixin for animation)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc watch this vid, its really useful